# Emoticon on keyboard support and Android version

Tags: keyboard, android-versions, emoticons

I am wondering since what version Android emoticon have been added?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on a variety of things, most importantly whether the vendor or manufacturer uses the Google keyboard or one of their own. Some apps, including Facebook and most manufacturer/vendor Messaging apps, have their own built-in emoticon support.

The default keyboard for Lollipop (5.0) on the AT&T Samsung Galaxy S5 has built-in emoticon support. If memory serves, Kitkat (4.4.2) did not.

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniemoji.com](http://caniemoji.com/android/)

> Android 4.3 Jelly Bean was the first release to include a built-in keyboard (iWnn IME), and Android 4.4 KitKat is the first to include a color emoji keyboard.
>
> Versions of Android prior to 4.3 require the use of a third-party keyboard app to insert emoji, or can copy/paste emoji from the list of all emoji.